# Knockout observableArray contains new item but UI doesn't update

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a best practice (at this point I'll take a half-decent practice) for adding a new item to a knockout observableArray when using a bootstrap 3 modal?  Currently I'm working with a deeply nested data structure and I've been able to add data down to a point. I have a bootstrap modal that is bound to a "selectedItem" on my view model.  The item is itself a member of an observableArray.  This works when I want to edit an existing item but fails when I try to add a new item.  The process I'm following is to new up the object I want to add (all observable properties), set the viewModel's SelectedItem property = the new object so the with binding in the modal works, then I push the new item to the observableArray and show the modal.  In the modal I add values to a few properties, including populating three observableArrays on the new item (which also fail at this point, probably the same problem) and close the modal. What's odd is that adding the new item only fails visually.  When I save the viewmodel back to the server and reload the page, the item that I just added is there now and renders properly.  I assume that I'm breaking the observableArray that I'm adding the object to, but I'm at my wits end trying to figure out how.  I've tried to make this into a fiddle, but because of the complexity I end up having to simplify it to the point that it works or that I'm no longer illustrating the behavior.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting beyond what Ryan Niemeyer suggests [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html) are welcome!  When I use the pre tag I can see the new data added to the observableArray, but the UI doesn't respond.  What's a guy to do?

EDIT: the relevant portion of the page is posted below.

View:

```
<div id="SchedulePanel" class="panel panel-default" > @*style="@showSchedule">*@

    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Plan Schedule</h3>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="visible: scheduleDirty" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 7px;">Save All</a>
        <div>
            Add
            <input id="numWeeks" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="number" value="1" />
            <a id="btnAddWeek" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addWeek">Week(s)</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="ScheduledInstructions">
            Click the Add Week button to get started adding workouts to your schedule
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div id="weeks" data-bind="foreach: Schedule">
            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <h4 style="display: inline-block;" >Week <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></h4>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" style="color: red;" data-bind="visible: IsDirty"></span>&nbsp;
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share" data-bind="visible: !IsDirty()" title="Click to copy this week and add to the end of the schedule"></span>
                <div data-bind="foreach: Days ">
                    <div class="dayBuilder">
                        Day <span data-bind="text: DayNumber"></span>
@*<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>*@
                        <div data-bind="foreach: Workouts ">
                            <div class="workout" title="Edit Workout" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <span data-bind="text: Type"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right removeWorkout" title="Remove Workout"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="newWorkout addWorkout">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" title="Add Workout"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="newWorkout" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newWorkoutLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="with: $root.SelectedWorkout">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-wide">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="newWorkoutLabel"><span data-bind="text: Type"></span> Workout</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Select workout type</label>                        
                        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.WorkoutEnum, new { @class="form-control", data_bind="value: Type"})    
                    </div>

                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <h3 class="workoutHeader">Warmup</h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" data-section="warmup" title="Add Interval"></span>
                        <div id="newWarmupInterval" style="display: none;">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="WUDistance" id="WUDistanceBasedT" class="wuDistance" value="true" checked> Distance Based
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="WUDistance" id="WUDistanceBasedF" class="wuDistance"  value="false"> Time Based
                            </label>
                            <div id="timeBasedWU" style="display: none;" class="tp-intervalInputContainer form-inline">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">Enter a new time based interval to be added to the Warmup portion of this workout, in the style of '15 minutes @(Model.IsRPE ? "at RPE5'" : "easy'") </div>
                                <input type="text" id="timeValueWU" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Time" style="width: 60px;"/>
                                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.TimeUnits, new { @class="form-control", id="timeUnitWU"})
                                @(Model.IsRPE ? Html.EnumDropDownListFor( m => m.RPEUnitsEnum, new {@class = "form-control", id="rpeUnitTimeWU"} ) : Html.EnumDropDownListFor( m => m.HeartRateZoneEnum, new {@class = "form-control", id="hrUnitTimeWU"} ))
                                <div id="btnSaveWU" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Save</div>
                                <div id="btnCancelWU" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cancel</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="distanceBasedWU" class="tp-intervalInputContainer form-inline">
                                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">Enter a new distance based interval to be added to the Warmup portion of this workout, in the style of '10 miles @(Model.IsRPE ? "at RPE5'" : "easy'") </div>
                                <input type="text" id="distValueWU" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Distance" style="width: 60px;"/>
                                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.DistanceUnitsEnum, new { @class="form-control", id="distUnitWU"})
                                @(Model.IsRPE ? Html.EnumDropDownListFor( m => m.RPEUnitsEnum, new {@class = "form-control", id="rpeUnitDistWU"} ) : Html.EnumDropDownListFor( m => m.HeartRateZoneEnum, new {@class = "form-control", id="hrUnitDistWU"} ))
                                <div id="btnSaveWU" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btnSaveWU">Save</div>
                                <div id="btnCancelWU" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cancel</div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        </div>

                        <ul id="WarmupIntervals" data-bind="template: { name: 'WorkoutTemplate', foreach: WarmUp }">
                            <li>
                                @if ( Model.IsTimeBased ) {
                                    <span data-bind="Text: TimeValue"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="Text: TimeUnit"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="Text: RPEValue, visible: $root.IsRPE"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="Text: HRValue, visible: !$root.IsRPE()"></span>
                                }
                                else {
                                    <span data-bind="Text: DistanceValue"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="Text: DistanceUnit"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="Text: RPEValue, visible: $root.IsRPE"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="Text: HRValue, visible: !$root.IsRPE()"></span>
                                }
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <h3 class="workoutHeader">Main</h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"  data-section="main" title="Add Interval"></span>
                        <div id="newMainInterval" style="display: none;">
                            Need to get some content in here.
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <ul id="MainIntervals" data-bind="template: { name: 'WorkoutTemplate', foreach: Main }">
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <h3 class="workoutHeader">Cool Down</h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"  data-section="cooldown" title="Add Interval"></span>
                        <div id="newCooldownInterval" style="display: none;">
                            Need to get some content in here.
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <ul id="CoolDownIntervals" data-bind="template: { name: 'WorkoutTemplate', foreach: CoolDown }">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>*@
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary saveWorkout">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var trainingPlan;
var schedule;
var workoutNumber = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    // the plan object is a training plan with a few properties that describe the plan
    // along with a list of weeks that contain the workouts.  The weeks are broken down into days,
    // each day has a list of workouts, each workout has a list of intervals for its warm up, main and cool down
    // properties. 

    var planID = { id: $('#ID').val() };

    var Week = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = '';
        self.IsDirty = ko.observable(false);
        self.PlanID = ko.observable();
        self.StartDate = ko.observable();
        self.EndDate = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.Days = ko.observableArray([]); // a list of day objects
    };
    var Day = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = '';
        self.DayNumber = ko.observable();
        self.TodaysDate = ko.observable();
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.Workouts = ko.observableArray([]); // a list of workout objects
    };
    var Workout = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = '';
        self.Type = ko.observable(); //need to figure out what/how to handle enums
        self.WarmUp = ko.observableArray([]); // a list of intervals
        self.Main = ko.observableArray([]); // a list of intervals
        self.CoolDown = ko.observableArray([]); // a list of intervals
        self.Status = ko.observable();
        self.Completed = ko.observable();
    };
    var Interval = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.IsTimeBased = ko.computed(function() {
            return !self.IsDistanceBased;
        });
        self.IsDistanceBased = ko.observable();
        self.TimeValue = ko.observable();
        self.TimeUnit = ko.observable();
        self.RPEUnits = ko.observable();
        self.HeartRateZone = ko.observable();
        self.Description = ko.observable();
        self.DistanceValue = ko.observable();
        self.DistanceUnit = ko.observable();
    };

    $.getJSON('/PlanBuilder/GetPlanJson', planID, function(model) {

        // map model into a knockout viewModel
        trainingPlan = ko.mapping.fromJSON(model.Message);

        // setup regular and computed observables
        trainingPlan.SelectedWorkout = ko.observable();
        trainingPlan.SelectedInterval = ko.observable();
        trainingPlan.SelectedDay = ko.observable();
        trainingPlan.Weeks = ko.computed(function() {
            return trainingPlan.Schedule().length;
        });
        trainingPlan.TotalWeeks = ko.computed(function() {
            trainingPlan.Weeks = trainingPlan.Schedule.length || 0;
            return trainingPlan.Schedule.length || 0;
        }, this);
        trainingPlan.TotalDays = ko.computed(function() {
            return trainingPlan.Schedule.length * 7 || 0;
        }, this);

        // setup $root methods
        trainingPlan.addWeek = function() {
            var numberOfWeeks = $('#numWeeks').val();

            if (numberOfWeeks < 1)
                numberOfWeeks = 1;

            for (var w = 1; w <= numberOfWeeks; w++) {

                var wk = new Week();
                wk.IsDirty(true);
                var wkNum = this.Schedule().length + 1;
                var firstDay = wkNum > 1 ? (wkNum - 1) * 7 + 1 : 1; // day number of first day of new week

                wk.Name = wkNum;
                wk.PlanID = $('#ID').val();

                for (var i = firstDay; i < firstDay + 7; i++) {
                    var dy = new Day();
                    dy.DayNumber = i;
                    wk.Days.push(dy);
                }

                //var summ = new day();
                //summ.DayNumber = "Summary";
                //wk.Days.push(summ);

                this.Schedule.push(wk);
            }

            // update # of weeks in training plan
            trainingPlan.Weeks = this.Schedule().length + 1;
        };
        trainingPlan.addWorkout = function() {
            var wrk = new Workout();
            trainingPlan.SelectedWorkout(wrk);
            $('#newWorkout').modal('show');
        };
        trainingPlan.saveWorkout = function (wrk) {
            trainingPlan.SelectedDay().Workouts().push(wrk);
            $('#newWorkout').modal('hide');
        };
        trainingPlan.addInterval = function (workoutSection) {
            var intr = new Interval();
            trainingPlan.SelectedInterval(intr);

            var container = $(this).parent();
            intr.IsDistanceBased($('#WUDistanceBasedT').is(':checked'));

            if (intr.IsDistanceBased()) {
                intr.DistanceUnit(container.find('#distUnitWU').val());
                intr.DistanceValue(container.find('#distValueWU').val());
                if (!trainingPlan.IsRPE()) {
                    intr.HeartRateZone(container.find('#hrUnitDistWU').val());
                } else {
                    intr.RPEUnits(container.find('#rpeUnitDistWU').val());
                }
            } else {
                intr.TimeUnit(container.find('#timeUnitWU').val());
                intr.TimeValue(container.find('#timeValueWU').val());
                if (!trainingPlan.IsRPE()) {
                    intr.HeartRateZone(container.find('#hrUnitTimeWU').val());
                } else {
                    intr.RPEUnits(container.find('#rpeUnitTimeWU').val());
                }
            }

            trainingPlan.SelectedWorkout().WarmUp().push(intr);
        };
        trainingPlan.copyWeek = function(index) {
            var weeks = trainingPlan.Schedule().slice(index, index + 1);
            var week = weeks[0];

            var newWeek = new Week();
            var weekNum = parseInt(trainingPlan.Schedule().length) + 1;

            newWeek.EndDate = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(week.EndDate));
            newWeek.IsDirty = ko.observable(true);
            newWeek.Name = ko.observable(weekNum);
            newWeek.PlanID = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(week.PlanID));
            newWeek.StartDate = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(week.StartDate));

            var dayNumber = 1;

            week.Days().forEach(function(day, dayIndex) {
                var newDay = new Day();
                var daysBase = trainingPlan.Schedule().length * 7;
                var currentDay = daysBase + dayIndex + 1;

                newDay.Name = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(day.Name));
                newDay.DayNumber = ko.observable(currentDay);
                newDay.Name = ko.observable("Day " + currentDay);

                day.Workouts().forEach(function(workout) {
                    var newWorkout = new Workout();
                    newWorkout.Completed = false;

                    workout.WarmUp().forEach(function(interval) {
                        var newInterval = new Interval();
                        newInterval.Description = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(interval.Description));
                    });

                    newWorkout.Type = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(workout.Type));

                    newDay.Workouts.push(newWorkout);
                });

                newWeek.Days.push(newDay);
            });

            trainingPlan.Schedule.push(newWeek);
        };
        trainingPlan.scheduleDirty = ko.computed(function() {
            var dirty = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < trainingPlan.Schedule().length; i++) {
                if (trainingPlan.Schedule()[i].IsDirty())
                    dirty = true;
            }
            ;
            return dirty;
        }, this);

        // lets get it on
        ko.applyBindings(trainingPlan);
    });

    $('#weeks').on('click', '.removeWorkout', function() {
        var context = ko.contextFor(this);
        var workouts = context.$parent.Workouts;
        workouts.remove(context.$data);
        context.$parents[1].IsDirty(true);
    });

    $('#weeks').on('click', '.addWorkout', function() {
        var context = ko.contextFor(this);
        context.$parent.IsDirty(true);
        var wrk = new Workout();
        wrk.Type("Flying");
        //trainingPlan.SelectedWorkout(wrk);
        context.$data.Workouts().push(wrk);
        //$('#newWorkout').modal('show');
    });

    $('#newWorkout').on('click', '.saveWorkout', function () {
        $('#newWorkout').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#weeks').on('click', '.workout', function() {
        var context = ko.contextFor(this);
        context.$root.SelectedWorkout(context.$data);
        $('#newWorkout').modal('show');
    });


    // Week functions
    $('#weeks').on('click', 'span.glyphicon-floppy-disk', function() {
        var context = ko.contextFor(this);
        var weekData = ko.mapping.toJSON(context.$data);

        var $btn = $(this);

        // save week
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PlanBuilder/SaveWeek",
            type: "POST",
            data: weekData,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data.responseText);
                $btn.find('span.glyphicon-floppy-disk').addClass('btn-danger');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.IsError) {
                    $btn.find('span.glyphicon-floppy-disk').addClass('btn-danger');
                    $btn.text('Error');
                } else {
                    $btn.removeClass('glyphicon-floppy-disk').addClass('glyphicon-floppy-saved');
                    $btn.css('color', 'green');
                    // add newly generated ID to knockout week object
                    context.$data.ID = data.Message;
                    context.$data.IsDirty(false);
                    $btn.css('color', 'red');

                    // after 3 seconds fadeOut save button and reset the glyphicon classes
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $btn.removeClass('glyphicon-floppy-saved').addClass('glyphicon-floppy-disk');
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        });

    });
    $('#weeks').on('click', 'span.glyphicon-share', function() {
        var context = ko.contextFor(this);
        var index = context.$index();
        context.$root.copyWeek(index);
    });

     //Workout functions
    $('#newWorkout').on('click', 'span.glyphicon-plus-sign', function () {

        var section = $(this).attr('data-section');

        if (section === 'warmup') {
           $('#newWarmupInterval').slideToggle();
        }

        if (section === 'main') {
            $('#newMainInterval').slideToggle();
        }

        if (section === 'cooldown') {
            $('#newCoolDownInterval').slideToggle();
        }


    });

    $('#newWorkout').on('click', '.wuDistance', function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'WUDistanceBasedT') {
            $('#timeBasedWU').fadeOut(function () {
                $('#distanceBasedWU').fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            $('#distanceBasedWU').fadeOut(function () {
                $('#timeBasedWU').fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });

    $('#newWorkout').on('click', '.btnSaveWU', function () {
        var context = ko.contextFor(this);



    });

    $('#btnSaveM').click(function () { });
    $('#btnSaveCD').click(function () { });



    $('#btnSavePlan').click(function() {

        // if form is valid, let's save this shiz
        if ($('#NewPlanForm').valid()) {

            var mappingOptions = {
                'ignore': ["addWorkout", "removeWorkout", "Schedule"]
            };

            var datum = ko.mapping.toJSON(trainingPlan, mappingOptions);

            var $btn = $(this);

            // save plan
            $.ajax({
                url: "/PlanBuilder/SavePlan",
                type: "POST",
                data: datum,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.responseText);
                    $btn.firstChild().addClass('btn-danger');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.IsError) {
                        $btn.firstChild().addClass('btn-danger');
                        $btn.text('Error');
                    } else {
                        $btn.addClass('btn-success');
                        $btn.text('Success');
                        $('#ID').val(data.Message);

                        $('#SchedulePanel').show();

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $btn.removeClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary');
                        }, 4000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post your example showing the non-working version. Of course a jsfiddle showing only what is really necessary to replicate the problem would be better. You write "simplify it to the point that it works", Couldn't you identify the step that takes your simplified example from working to non-working and make a sample showing that specifically?

Comment: Had more time to think about how to post a sample while riding the train to work, going to try now.

Comment: The code helps, but wow, that's one wall of text to wade through. Any chance you can reduce it down to an [sscce](http://sscce.org)? This would make it a lot more inviting and easier for us to help you.

Comment: Yeah, I know sorry.  Posted that from the train on a laptop monitor.  Going to try to break it down to only the relevant stuff.

Comment: And, if possible, please also make a jsfiddle/jsbin/plunker. That is likely to help anyone trying to assist you by making their work a bit easier.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?  Or are we not allowed to bring our questions to Stack anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of code to parse through, but I noticed that a lot of your pushing is being done on the value of an observableArray, and not the observableArray itself. Fixing that across your javascript might be your issue.

```
    trainingPlan.saveWorkout = function (wrk) {
            //trainingPlan.SelectedDay().Workouts().push(wrk);
            trainingPlan.SelectedDay().Workouts.push(wrk);
            $('#newWorkout').modal('hide');
```

Comment: Thanks scary, I'll give that a shot.  Busy at work today, but will try to get this into a fiddle with only the relevant bits if possible.

Comment: Cool. Make sure to search for "push" and replace all the instances, not just the example I plucked.

Comment: Not sure if you're a fan of Harlem Nights (if not Google it), but Scary, you're one sweet smart MF.  :)  I don't know how I missed that (or why it seems to be working in other areas of my app) but it definitely was the () on the end of the arrays that was preventing me from pushing to them.  THANKS!  I've been stuck on this for about a week.  Luckily it's a side project and not my day job!